# How to Disable Internet connection without disabling the LAN network

Tags: networking

How to Disable Internet connection without disabling the LAN network
i want disable some computer internet connection but  must work printer .

Comment: network configuration (computers?, routers? )? operating system? done from command line? from browser? from pushing buttons on a router? telepathically?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.

**The first and easy one** is to **remove** the **default gateway** from these computers.

If your computers are working together on Layer2 (same subnet) it will work. I guess this option will work for you.

**Otherwise**- you will have to configure some rules in your router.

Comment: pleases can you sent video? how do it ?